# Catch UITapGesture on programmatically created UITextView

Tags: swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm creating `UITextView` (a subclass of) programmatically and want to show a popover view, or something else, when user taps on the created `UITextView`. Showing popover view is not my problem, but catching tap gesture is:

```
func createCustomText(text:String){
    var tvControl = CustomTextView(frame: CGRectMake(CGFloat(Int.random(50...100)), 
        CGFloat(Int.random(50...100)), 100, 30))
    tvControl.text = text
    baseView.addSubview(tvControl)
    tvControl.font = UIFont(name: "BigruixianthinGB1.0", size: 12)
    tvControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    activeTextView = tvControl
    var tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:tvControl, action:"detectTap:")
    tvControl.gestureRecognizers = [tapRecognizer]
}

func detectTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    println("tap tap")
}
```

But it causes an error:

> 2015-08-12 10:35:13.665 My App[7030:481148] -[My_App.CustomTextView detectTap:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe8ba813200
>   2015-08-12 10:35:13.673 My App[7030:481148] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[My_App.CustomTextView detectTap:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe8ba813200'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error is that the `target` of the `UITapGestureRecognizer` is set to `tvControl` which means `detectTap:` will be called on the instance of the `CustomTextView`.

The gesture recognizer's `target` should be set to `self`:

```
var tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:"detectTap:")
```